# Add Virtual attribute to active record object to output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a custom method in my model called "file_url(:thumb)" to receive a specific thumbnail file URL.  The method is provided by the carrierwave gem.

It is not stored in my database.  How can I add this virtual attribute to @document so when I convert to json it's included?

```
module Api
  module V1
    class DocumentsController < ApiController      

      respond_to :json

      def show
        @document = Document.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: @document }
          format.xml { render xml: @document }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define your own [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) method in the Document model. Something like this would do the trick:

```
def as_json(options = { })
  h = super(options)
  h[:thumb_url] = file_url(:thumb)
  h
end
```